# Compare strings in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

My dataframe looks like:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~order_id, ~user_id,      ~comp_order,           ~comp_rec,
    1164320,    32924, "4-6-22-11-37-5", "4-5-6-11-22-36-37",
    1169182,    33128,  "9-4-15-28-8-7",  "4-7-8-9-28-37-38",
    1166014,    33003,    "27-22-4-6-5", "4-5-6-22-27-36-37",
    1166019,    32996,    "27-22-4-6-8", "4-6-8-22-27-36-38"
  )
```

I want to know what digit is present in the comp_order column and not in the comp_rec.

The final output should look like:

```
  order_id user_id comp_rec          comp_order     is_equal elements_removed_from_rec elements_added_to_order
     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>             <chr>          <chr>    <chr>                     <chr>                  
1  1164320   32924 4-5-6-11-22-36-37 4-6-22-11-37-5 no       36                        none                   
2  1169182   33128 4-7-8-9-28-37-38  9-4-15-28-8-7  no       37                        none                   
3  1166014   33003 4-5-6-22-27-36-37 27-22-4-6-5    no       36-37                     none                   
4  1166019   32996 4-6-8-22-27-36-38 27-22-4-6-8    no       36-38                     none                   
5  1166012   32922 27-22-4-6-8       27-22-4-6-8    yes      none                      none                   
6  1166033   32911 27-22-4-6-8       27-22-4-6-8-33 no       none                      33                     

df_output <- tibble::tribble(
               ~order_id, ~user_id,           ~comp_rec,      ~comp_order, ~is_equal, ~elements_removed_from_rec, ~elements_added_to_order,
                 1164320,    32924, "4-5-6-11-22-36-37", "4-6-22-11-37-5",      "no",                       "36",                   "none",
                 1169182,    33128,  "4-7-8-9-28-37-38",  "9-4-15-28-8-7",      "no",                       "37",                   "none",
                 1166014,    33003, "4-5-6-22-27-36-37",    "27-22-4-6-5",      "no",                    "36-37",                   "none",
                 1166019,    32996, "4-6-8-22-27-36-38",    "27-22-4-6-8",      "no",                    "36-38",                   "none",
                 1166012,    32922,       "27-22-4-6-8",    "27-22-4-6-8",     "yes",                     "none",                   "none",
                 1166033,    32911,       "27-22-4-6-8", "27-22-4-6-8-33",      "no",                     "none",                     "33"
               )
```

I would need to know:

1. what has been removed from rec
2. what has been added to order

In terms of digits in the string.

The issues that the order of the digits in the string is not necessarily the same...

How can I make a comparison between these 2 strings?

Comment: Does the order of the digits matter at all?

Comment: Understand order may be different but is there a chance the strings are the same "length" but with different digits?

Comment: @coffeinjunky the order doesn't matter, I just would like to know what digit is present in one column but not in the other and vice versa..

Comment: I think line 2 of your expected output, added elements needs `"15"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach with `purrr`:

First, we use `purrr:map` to split the elements on `-` into a list of elements. Then, we use `purrr:map2` to perform `setdiff` on the lists to identify the different elements.

If both evaluate to `""`, then we know they are the same, and so we can use `case_when` to determine the `is_equal` column.

Then we can clean up by removing the list columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
  mutate(comp_order_list = map(comp_order, ~str_split(.,"-", simplify = TRUE)),
         comp_rec_list = map(comp_rec, ~str_split(.,"-", simplify = TRUE)),
         elements_removed = map2_chr(comp_rec_list,comp_order_list,
                                   ~ paste(setdiff(.x,.y),collapse = "-")),
         elements_added = map2_chr(comp_order_list,comp_rec_list,
                                     ~ paste(setdiff(.x,.y),collapse = "-")),
         is_equal = case_when(elements_removed == "" & elements_added == "" ~ "yes",
                              TRUE ~ "no")) %>%
  dplyr::select(order_id,user_id,comp_rec,comp_order,is_equal,elements_removed,elements_added)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  order_id user_id comp_rec          comp_order     is_equal elements_removed elements_added
     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>             <chr>          <chr>    <chr>            <chr>         
1  1164320   32924 4-5-6-11-22-36-37 4-6-22-11-37-5 no       "36"             ""            
2  1169182   33128 4-7-8-9-28-37-38  9-4-15-28-8-7  no       "37-38"          "15"          
3  1166014   33003 4-5-6-22-27-36-37 27-22-4-6-5    no       "36-37"          ""            
4  1166019   32996 4-6-8-22-27-36-38 27-22-4-6-8    no       "36-38"          ""            
5  1166012   32922 27-22-4-6-8       27-22-4-6-8    yes      ""               ""            
6  1166033   32911 27-22-4-6-8       27-22-4-6-8-33 no       ""               "33"
```

Comment: Ian just out of curiosity why are you converting to numeric before the `setdiff` and then going back to character with `map2_chr`?

Comment: Good question, probably not necessary. When I was formulating my answer I thought I might have to do some ordering of the list elements. But in the comments, it doesn't seem like the OP cares. I can clean that up.

Comment: No worries I was just curious if there was some edge case I didn't think of.  I was busy lumbering through it when you posted and so I was curious

Answer (score 2):

Here one way of doing it that utilises `setdiff` at its core:

```
# These two lines split the strings and store them in one cell in the dataframe
df$digits_order <- str_split(df$comp_order, "-")
df$digits_rec <- str_split(df$comp_rec, "-")

# The following apply function iterates over rows and applies setdiff. 
# paste is used to stitch them together if apply returns multiple digits.  
df$in_rec_but_not_order <- apply(df, 1, function(row) paste(setdiff(row$digits_rec, row$digits_order), collapse = "-"))
df$in_order_but_not_rec <- apply(df, 1, function(row) paste(setdiff(row$digits_order, row$digits_rec), collapse = "-"))

df
# A tibble: 4 x 8
  order_id user_id comp_order     comp_rec          digits_order digits_rec in_order_but_not_rec in_rec_but_not_order
     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>          <chr>             <list>       <list>     <chr>                <chr>               
1  1164320   32924 4-6-22-11-37-5 4-5-6-11-22-36-37 <chr [6]>    <chr [7]>  ""                   36                  
2  1169182   33128 9-4-15-28-8-7  4-7-8-9-28-37-38  <chr [6]>    <chr [7]>  15                   37-38               
3  1166014   33003 27-22-4-6-5    4-5-6-22-27-36-37 <chr [5]>    <chr [7]>  ""                   36-37               
4  1166019   32996 27-22-4-6-8    4-6-8-22-27-36-38 <chr [5]>    <chr [7]>  ""                   36-38
```

Here, the last column contains the digits missing from the record.